# How to get active kernel name in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I would like to make a notebook that prints the active kernel name.
I registered multiple venvs as kernels using the

```
python -m ipykernel install --user --name <kernel_name>
```

In the notebook I would like to print some metadata about the active kernel.

How can one get the name of the active kernel?

---

EDIT:

Here are the particular versions in my stack

```
ipykernel==4.5.2
ipython==5.3.0
jupyter==1.0.0
```

nevertheless, the question should be answered in general.

Comment: You may be able to get that info from `sys.executable`; that'll give you the interpreter path.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to do this is using Javascript within the notebook, and executing some code to make the string available in Python:

```
%%javascript
var kernel = Jupyter.notebook.kernel
kernel.execute('kernel_name = ' + '"' + kernel.name + '"')
```

Then you have the kernel name in Python:

```
print(kernel_name)
# my-kernel
```

As an added bonus, you can use the `jupyter_client` module to find more information about the kernel once you have its name:

```
from jupyter_client import kernelspec
spec = kernelspec.get_kernel_spec(kernel_name)
print(spec.resource_dir)
# /path/to/my/kernel
```

Comment: I get `Javascript Error: Jupyter is not defined` when using JupyterLab.

Comment: JupyterLab has an entirely different frontend javascript environment than Jupyter Notebook.

Answer (score 4):

In jupyterlab, [eduffy's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7536/eduffy) works

```
import sys
import os
kernel_name = os.path.basename(sys.executable.replace("/bin/python",""))
```